# Access violation - Why is base class destructor getting called twice?

Tags: c++, inheritance, decorator, access-violation, virtual-destructor

I have a class `Player` which attempts to implement the `Decorator` pattern. `Player`contains a member of its base class `Character` called `m_player`. When calling the destructor of `Player` from the client, I run into some problems resulting in a memory access violation. Starting in `main`:

```
Character* createBaseClass();

// more forward declarations

int main (int argc, char* const argv[]) 
{
    Player* mainCharacter = new Player(createBaseCharacter());

    delete mainCharacter;   // Crashes when calling delete

    return 0;
}

Character* createBaseCharacter()
{
    return Character::Builder()
        .name("Dylan")
        .description("Super bad-ass hero of the game")
        .build();
}
```

The error occurs shortly after I call the `delete` operator on `mainCharacter`, which has the following call sequence:

```
Player::~Player()
{
    delete m_armor;
    delete m_weapon;
    delete m_player;  // calls Character's destructor
}
```

Then the destructor for `Character`:

```
Character::~Character()
{
    // works fine
    //
    delete m_abilityAttributes;  
    m_abilityAttributes = NULL;
    delete m_primaryAttributes;
    m_primaryAttributes = NULL;
}
```

**However**, The strange thing is that this destructor appears to be getting called twice - once the above is done executing the debugger takes me to a disassembly stepping me through a "scalar deleting destructor", which appears to call the `Character` destructor again, by way of the interface for `Player`, called `CharacterDecorator`:

[image]

Call stack at point of crash:

[image]

Call to `CharacterDecorator`'s destructor results in subsequent call to `Character`'s destructor:

```
Character::~Character()
{
    // Crashes with Access Violation
    //
    delete m_abilityAttributes;  
    m_abilityAttributes = NULL;
    delete m_primaryAttributes;
    m_primaryAttributes = NULL;
}
```

At this point I am thoroughly confused - I am not sure why the destructor gets called again through the abstract interface `CharacterDecorator` in addition to the destructor getting called through its concrete implementation. Additionally, adding a destructor to `CharacterDecorator` doesn't appear to solve the problem.

For reference, I have included the implementation of `Player`, `Character` and the interface for `CharacterDecorator`:

```
class CharacterDecorator : public Character
{
public:

    virtual Armor* getArmor() const = 0;
    virtual Weapon* getWeapon() const = 0;
};
```

`Player`:

```
Player::Player()
{}

Player::Player(Character* player)
    :m_player(player)
    ,m_weapon(0)
    ,m_armor(0)
{}

Player::Player(Character* player, Weapon* weapon, Armor* armor)
    :m_player(player) 
    ,m_weapon(weapon)
    ,m_armor(armor)
{}

Player::~Player()
{
    delete m_armor;
    delete m_weapon;
}

// getters
Armor* Player::getArmor() const
{
    return m_armor;
}

Weapon* Player::getWeapon() const
{
    return m_weapon;
}

// additional methods ...
```

`Character`:

```
Character::Character()
{}

Character::Character(const Builder& builder)
    :m_name(builder._name)
    ,m_description(builder._description)
    ,m_abilityAttributes(builder._abilityAttributes)
    ,m_primaryAttributes(builder._primaryAttributes)
{}

Character::Character(const Character& rhs)
{
    m_name = rhs.m_name;
    m_description = rhs.m_description;
    m_abilityAttributes = new AbilityAttributes();
    m_primaryAttributes = new PrimaryAttributes();
    *m_abilityAttributes = *rhs.m_abilityAttributes;
    *m_primaryAttributes = *rhs.m_primaryAttributes;
}

Character::~Character()
{
    delete m_abilityAttributes;
    m_abilityAttributes = NULL;
    delete m_primaryAttributes;
    m_primaryAttributes = NULL;
}

// additional methods ...

// Builder pattern methods
//
Character::Builder::Builder()
    : _abilityAttributes(0), _primaryAttributes(0)
{}

Character* Character::Builder::build()
{
    return new Character(*this);
}

Character::Builder& Character::Builder::abilityAttributes(AbilityAttributes* value)
{
    _abilityAttributes = value;
    return *this;
}

Character::Builder& Character::Builder::primaryAttributes(PrimaryAttributes* value)
{
    _primaryAttributes = value;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Why are you copy creating a new character `new Character(player)` instead of using the one created by the factory?

Comment: I see that it is uneccessary now. I thought maybe my error initially was because I didn't do a deep copy, but that isn't the problem, obviously.

Comment: Could you simplify the code to the absolute minimum needed to reproduce the problem, and post the -- runnable -- result in its entirety?

Comment: Is it possible to try an approach relying on smart pointers? I recommend you to use unique_ptr or scoped_ptr and then try to figure out when a shared_ptr is needed. Maybe you will be able to track the origin of the problem.

Comment: try making pointers NULL(nullptr) after delete. Maybe you are deleting it twice...

Comment: @neagoegab: I tried that in `Character`'s destructor, but unfortunately it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: @neagoegab: call stack included above. i don't know if that will give you much information though. However, you can see that the second destructor call to ~Character after the highlighted line is when the program crashes.

Comment: @neagoegab: That would only hide the problem. No code path should accidentally delete things multiple times.

Comment: @Dylan: You need to severly reduce the pointer use in your code. Then replace every raw pointer with either `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`. `delete` in user-code is bad.

Comment: how m_player is created? new CharacterDecorator or new Character?
is Character destructor virtual?

Comment: @neagoegab then he also needs to put up guards on his delete to test for null and skip deleting if it is null.

Comment: @StarPilot it is safe to delete zero in C++, no need for guards.

Comment: @GManNickG: I know that smart pointers are the preferred method. I have never used them before, but will try refactoring my code to support them. Even so, there must be some reason for the above error, your suggestions aside.

Comment: @Dylan As others have suggested, reduce reduce reduce your code.  Comment out armor, weapons, attributes, and anything else that isn't strictly needed to see the problem.  Then add log statements in any and all constructors/destructors to get an exact picture of the order things are getting constructed/destructed in.  With this information (ideally a small code sample that reproduces your problem), we can help you more.

Comment: @Dylan Does `Player` inherit from `CharacterDecorator`?  I.e. `class Player : public CharacterDecorator` in your header file (which you didn't include)?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that. I didn't include the headers for the sake of brevity (kind of irrelevant at this point, I know). In any case, I fixed my problem after much effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I provided a Constructor that takes no arguments, I didn't give it an initialization list for the members of pointer type:

```
Character::Character() 
{}
```

Should be:

```
Character::Character() 
    : m_abilityAttributes(0), m_primaryAttributes(0)
{}
```

I guess this is because the constructor for the base class `Character` gets called when I instantiate an object of `Player`, but the default constructor for the base class didn't have an member initialization list before, hence the access violation error when calling the base destructor (?)

Comment: That's exactly right.  When your Player is constructed, it also constructs the Character as a base class.  Without initializing the members in your constructor, these members are going to be random values.  When the Player is destructed, the Character destructor is called, which deletes those members, except they are random values, causing your access violation.

Comment: C++ can be such a harsh mistress sometimes. I occasionally forget the little (yet very important) details.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Player` class inherits from `CharacterDecorator`, which inherits from `Character`. So when you call the destructor on a `Player` object, you will delete the m_player object (calling its `Character` destructor) then again on the base `Character` part of the `Player` object. On top of the fact that I do not that is what you want to do, you have also the problem that when you created the `Player`, the default `Character` constructor was called to create the base `Character` object, and this one does not initialize anything in the `Character` part of `Player` i.e. fields like `m_abilityAttributes` and `m_primaryAttributes` that you delete in the `Character` destructor.

Now, it seems you have one too may `Character` in your `Player`. You probably want to have your `Player` constructor taking a `Character::Builder` reference instead of a `Character` pointer, which would be used to initialize/build the base `Character` of your 'CharacterDecorator`(and you may have to have a`CharacterDecorator`constructor taking a`Character::Builder`object to initialize its`Character` base).

(note: having a m_player member pointing to a `Character` was a red flag to me)

Comment: The second sentence of the first paragraph I figured out below, but I should probably refactor the code using your suggestion in paragraph two. Thanks.